# sql syntax the insert command using in razor webmatrix

Tags: asp.net, sql, razor

is there any probleme with this sql  syntax

```
  @{
var userId = Request["UserId"];
     var db = Database.Open("intranet");
    var query3 = "INSERT INTO CongeAccept(UserId,DateDebut,DateFin,TypeConge) SELECT UserId,DateDebutDemande,DateFinDemande,TypeConge FROM DemandeConge WHERE UserId = '" + userId + "'";
            db.Execute(query3); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any probleme with this sql syntax

It largely depends on where the userID is coming from. If its user supplied you're opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack

You should use parameters instead. As added bonus you don't have to worry about putting quotes around the values.

```
 var query3 = @"INSERT INTO CongeAccept(UserId,DateDebut,DateFin,TypeConge) 
               SELECT UserId,DateDebutDemande,DateFinDemande,TypeConge 
               FROM DemandeConge 
               WHERE UserId = @0";
 db.Execute(query3, userId );
```

Comment: tnks fr the notice dudde ^^ so when i want to use a variable name i put "@" before the var name ?

Comment: Yeah but the variable name doesn't actually matter since it replaces by the order it appears. See the [Database.Execute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.execute(v=vs.99).aspx)

Comment: unfortunately :s :s it shows me this msg : A parameter is missing. http://imageup.fr/uploads/1330386509.png

Comment: it should be `db.Execute(query3, UserId )` not `db.Execute(query3)`

Comment: i already use it but it doesn't work they show me this msg : http://imageup.fr/uploads/1330386739.png

Comment: sorry in `userId` the U should be lower case to match `var userId`

Comment: yes yes it solved bu i steel get the same problem :s :s http://imageup.fr/uploads/1330386879.png

Comment: turns out WebMatrix is very specific about its parameter names. It must be @0, @1, @2 etc

Comment: yes i turned it .. now they didn't show me the ereur msg but the comaande can't insert the data into the CongeAccept table :s :s